# Не выполняется CMD в docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker

Превед всем!

Значит собираю я docker-контейнер

```
FROM perl:5.20

COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

ENV PATH "$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/bin"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib"
ENV ORACLE_HOME "/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64"
ENV TNS_ADMIN "/usr/src/myapp"
ENV NLS_LANG "AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8"

RUN cpanm DBI

CMD [ "bash", "./ora_install.sh" ]

RUN cpanm Date::Format AnyEvent AnyEvent::Fork AnyEvent::Fork::Pool

WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

CMD [ "perl", "./test.pl" ]
```

В котором пытаюсь выполнить `ora_install.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

POS=`pwd`

touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/repa.list
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/repa.list
deb http://tut.moya.repa jessie main contrib non-free
EOF

apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com MOY_KEY
apt-get update && apt-get install --quiet --assume-yes \
 oracle-instantclient12.1-basic \
 oracle-instantclient12.1-devel \
 oracle-instantclient12.1-odbc \
 oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus
apt-get clean

wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.74.tar.gz
tar xzf DBD-Oracle-1.74.tar.gz
cd DBD-Oracle-1.74
perl Makefile.PL -l
make
make install

cd $POS
```

Сборка контейнера проходит [без проблем](https://pastebin.com/eAN18Rrw), но он почему-то отказывается выполнять `CMD [ "bash", "./ora_install.sh" ]` . В интерактивном режиме эта команда выполняется успешно.

Вопрос: Что я не так делаю? Может как-то иначе нужно это делать? Как мне сказать ему, чтоб он выполнил всё, что находится в `ora_install.sh` ?

Answer (score 2):

Вызывать его через `RUN` , я понял.